# ValueError : Truth value Series is ambiguous

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I searched for this in other threads but could not find an answer.

I have a dictionary where key is month and value is a dataframe. Here is the structure of the dataframe(with all dummy values)

```
    year    type            amount  #rows
0   2016    mtd_res           800      4
0   2016    mtd_unres           0      0
0   2015    mtd_res             0      0
0   2015    mtd_unres           0      0
0   2015    mtd_total_res   70000     12
0   2015    mtd_res_rem     70000     12
0   2016    mtd_exp_res     70800     16   
Name: #rows, dtype: int64
```

I stored this in test variable

```
test = mtd[year_month[4:]]  # mtd is the dictionary
test[test['year'] == '2015'] <-- this statement gave an error :
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Not sure why I am getting this.
When I tried the below, it worked fine.

```
>>> test[test['mtd_type']=='mtd_res']
    year    mtd_type    amount  #rows
0   2016    mtd_res       800     4  
0   2015    mtd_res         0     0
```

Here are the data types for `test`:

```
>>> test.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 8 entries, 0 to 0
Data columns (total 4 columns):
year         8 non-null object
mtd_type     8 non-null object
BannerRev    8 non-null int64
#rows        8 non-null object
dtypes: int64(1), object(3)
memory usage: 320.0+ bytes
```

I tried using `.any()` and `.all()`, but nothing worked. Please let me know if I am missing anything here.

Comment: you're going to have to post input data and code to reproduce this

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this error. It is interesting to note that everything in `test` is an object except for the `BannerRev` (amount?). Can you paste the results of `test.to_dict()`?

Comment: Thanks for the response - EdChum and Alexander. I looked into it, in one of the columns(year) , there was a series object and not value and hence the error. Removing that resolved the issue.